# SSID geolocation. Is it possible to locate an AP by knowing its SSID?

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude, wireless, ssid, wifi

I am doing a research project about data leakage in probe requests. As in these probe requests it is possible to see some SSIDs, I was wandering if it could be possible to locate them. For example, if I see WLAN_C11G I would like to be capable of knowing the coordinates where this AP is.

I know that I could do my own database of scanned SSIDs. However, I would like to know if there is some public database where I can find some AP-SSID geolocations.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, AIUI Google use this as a basis for Android geolocation services, but I don't know if you can access that data/API directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is known as Wi-Fi Positioning. The information on actual databases in the Wikipedia article may be dated, though.

For years the big name in the field was Skyhook http://www.skyhookwireless.com/submit-access-point

A serious concern about privacy has been raised a number of years ago http://www.zdnet.com/article/mobile-privacy-flap-take-two-starring-google-skyhook-gps-act/

Answer (score 0):

Google has a private database :)

How accurate do you need to be for your application? i.e. in metres?